# Make a .batch file to start/stop a program?

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch (.bat) file that opens a program if it's not open, and stops the program if it is open. I have a game where when the launcher is closed, it stays open in the background. And I have to end it with task manager or else I can't launch it because steam doesn't like it when an app is open two times (it doesn't allow it), so I would like a batch file that does this for me, then bind it to a macro.

Answer (score 8):

To check if your programm is running : (Here an example with `notepad.exe`)

```dos
@echo off
Set "MyProcess=Notepad.exe"

tasklist | find /i "%MyProcess%">nul  && echo %MyProcess% Is running || echo %MyProcess% Is not running
```

So you can do like that :

```dos
@echo off
Set "MyProcess=Notepad.exe"

tasklist | find /i "%MyProcess%">nul  && Taskkill /F/IM  "%MyProcess%" || start "%MyProcess%"
```

Comment: I understand the taskkill does not require the program to be active when running that command. However, as the OP asked, is there a way to check if the program is running? I am interested.

Comment: Ok so that pretty much did what I already had, it runs the program either way, but never ends it. here's my old code:

@echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq Launcher.exe" |find ":" > nul
if errorlevel 1 taskkill /f /im "Launcher.exe"
if errorlevel 0 start steam://rungameid/243870
exit

Comment: You're just killing the `Laucher.exe` in this code. What will be with `taskkill /F/IM "steam.exe"`

Comment: No the code I currently have opens the Launcher.exe, and when I run it again, (while the launcher is open) it shuts the launcher and re-opens it?

Comment: Yes, but what's the name of the process opened by the `laucher.exe`

Comment: Launcher.exe is the process, its name is Launcher, and in order to open it properly through steam i have to use start steam://rungameid/24387

Comment: @echo off
    tasklist /fi "imagename eq Launcher.exe" |find ":" > nul
    if errorlevel 0 taskkill /f /im "Launcher.exe" && exit
    start steam://rungameid/243870

Comment: If taskkill don't kill it. I really don't now, You'll better ask this on a steam forum : http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do it:

```
@echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq Launcher.exe" |find "." > nul && taskkill /f /im "Launcher.exe" & goto :EOF
tasklist /fi "imagename eq Launcher.exe" |find "." > nul || start "" steam://rungameid/243870 & goto :EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

So I figured this out:

```
@echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq Launcher.exe" |find ":" > nul
if errorlevel 0 taskkill /f /im "Launcher.exe" && exit
start steam://rungameid/243870
exit
```

The logic behind it is that if you can kill the process, then end the prompt before you can create a new session of the process. But if the process can't be killed, then make a new session of it, then end the prompt.