# Batch script that will check if application is running, if it is, continue with the rest of the script

Tags: batch-file

I have this program that will spit out an error pop up every now and then.  I have to hit OK then restart the program to get it running again

I want to write a script that will check for this "ERROR" in applications under Task Manager every 10 seconds and if its running, kill it and then run the program.  Is it possible?

This is what i got so far.

```
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq ERROR.exe"
taskkill /f /im "ERROR.exe"
start program.exe
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: create a script that taskkills you program and then create a scheduled task on it to run every 10 seconds for X time

Comment: The program actually starts another process called "Error.exe" when it has a problem? That's a badly designed program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330273/make-a-batch-file-to-start-stop-a-program/23330320#23330320