# Break infinite loop with taskkill

Tags: batch-file

I trying to do an infinite loop to check if `node.exe` is using over some number of memory. Like this:

```
:loop2
sleep
taskkill /f /im node.exe "memusage gt 85000" > nul
timeout /t 30
GOTO loop2
```

But how can I break this infinite loop, when the `taskkill` is processed?

Comment: Does `taskkill` set ERRORLEVEL when the condition is met or not met?

Comment: No, how can I do that? I am trying to understand how implement this [link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php)

Comment: You could use `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq ADTConsole.exe"` to see If an image is still running. But, this will not help if you can have other images that you do not want to kill.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330273/make-a-batch-file-to-start-stop-a-program/23330320#23330320

Answer (score 2):

```
set "Myprocess=node.exe"
:test
tasklist | find /i "%MyProcess%">nul  && Taskkill /F /IM  "%MyProcess%" & exit/b
timeout /t 30
goto:test
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
:loop2
    sleep
    ( taskkill /f /im node.exe /fi "memusage gt 85000" | find "PID" >nul ) || (
        timeout /t 30
        GOTO loop2
    )
```

Check the output of the command to determine if a process has been killed.

**Edited** I thought the `PID` string was locale independent, but it is not. If needed, the `find` command can be replaced by

```
find /i "node.exe" > nul
```

to search for the name of the process in the output, or

```
findstr /r /c:" [1-9][0-9]*[02468][\., ]" > nul
```

to search for the presence of a process ID (note: all process IDs are multiple of 4)

Comment: I would change `find "PID"` to `find "SUCCESS"`. "PID" is output even if `taskkill` is failed.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov, `SUCESS` is locale depended while `PID` is not, and the question (at least as it has been done) does not require difference between sucess or failure in the operation or what to do if more than one process is found and some can be killed and some not. Anyway, thank you, one more option to the OP.

Comment: You are right - `taskkill` issues a message that locale depended. But, for example, in ru-RU locale there is no word `PID` in `taskkill` message - Ошибка: Не удается завершить процесс "PING.EXE" с идентификатором 10536. 
Причина: Отказано в доступе.

Comment: And this is a successful result - Успешно: Процесс "PING.EXE", с идентификатором 8568, был завершен.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov, I searched for `taskkill` command output, and I have to admit that [this](http://goo.gl/UUnQJs) convinced me. My fault. The only locale independent way to do it that I see at this moment is to check for the presence of a process ID number or the name of the process to kill.

Comment: Another method is to use `chcp` at the beginning of the script, for instance `chcp 65001` works for me (all messages are output in English, so `find` works correctly).

Comment: @DmitrySokolov, It is the first time I see any reference to this. In my case, working in a spanish locale windows version, changing the pagecode does not affect the output language, only the set of characters shown in console. Maybe it works in your locale, but I think (maybe I'm wrong, of course) that `chcp` is not a reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, for any locale.

```
:loop2
sleep
set _tk=
for /f "skip=1 delims=, tokens=2" %%A in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq node.exe" /fi "memusage gt 85000" /fo csv') do (
    taskkill /f /pid %%~A
    set _tk=1
)
if not "%_tk%"=="1" (
    timeout /t 30
    GOTO loop2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `TASKLIST` to see if a matching image is running. This code is -not- tested.

```
:loop2

SET TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\tk_%RANDOM%.tmp

TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FI "MEMUSAGE gt 9000" >"%TEMPFILE%"
SET /P TKI=<"%TEMPFILE%"
IF "%TKI%" EQU "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria." (GOTO OutOfIt)

taskkill /f /im node.exe "memusage gt 85000" > nul
timeout /t 30
GOTO loop2

:OutOfIt
IF EXISTS "%TEMPFILE%" (DEL "%TEMPFILE%")
EXIT /B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
taskkill /IM notepad.exe /FI "memusage gt 999" |find "SUCCESS" &&GOTO :BREAKOUT
```