# Can't remove a part of string batch

Tags: batch-file

I made a batch file to run `test`and run `test1`if it's not running already
however  when i run it

```
  @echo off

start test.exe  >nul 2>nul

tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq test1.exe">tmp.t
set /p "isRunning=<tmp.t"
%isRunning%>test1.txt
pause
IF NOT /i %isRunning:INFO=%==%isRunning% (start X:\X\test1.exe >nul 2>nul)
timeout 10
del tmp.t
```

it says

```
'INFO:' Is not regonized as an internal or external command,operable program
or batch file
```

then

```
:was unexpected at the time
```

Also test1.txt remains empty . this line `IF NOT /i %isRunning:~INFO=%==%isRunning%` was sopposed to check if proccess is running or not . it seems 
like string substitution isn't working the way it should    `%isRunning:INFO=%`

i can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better do it using `&&` and `||` operators :

```
@echo off
Set "MyProcess=test1.exe"

tasklist | find /i "%MyProcess%">nul  && echo %MyProcess% Is running || start "" "X:\X\test1.exe" >nul
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330273/make-a-batch-file-to-start-stop-a-program/23330320#23330320)

***And just to answer (to a part of) your question :***

the `/i` parameter have to be placed directly after the `if` statement.

Putting *double quote* between the tested variables avoid an error if the string is empty :

```
IF /i NOT "%isRunning:INFO=%"=="%isRunning%" (start X:\X\test1.exe >nul 2>nul)
```