# Using batch, if a Python script closes, how can i use batch to keep it open?

Tags: python, batch-file

I have 3 discord bots. Sometimes their scripts close when my WiFi dips up and down <sup>(thanks, Comcast)</sup>.

I have a little experience with batch but I am stuck coming up with a batch script that detects when a certain program closes.

Assume I have the following files:

```
bot1-1.py
bot1-2.py
bot2-1.py
bot2-2.py
bot-3.py
```

What's the best way to open these files again if they close?

I would like the batch program to detect when any of the python programs close and reopen them.

Thanks to all who attempt to find an answer.

EDIT: This question is very similar to [Make a .batch file to start/stop a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330273/make-a-batch-file-to-start-stop-a-program)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a .batch file to start/stop a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330273/make-a-batch-file-to-start-stop-a-program)

Comment: @SachaDee I think that question you linked should work for my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that when the Internet drops, you get an error since of connection.
Use `try:` and `except:`, so if there is no Internet the program won't close.
I hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you not to use a batchfile for that: just as your Python scripts can be closed, so can you batchfile.

You can register your scripts as services. Like that, Windows technology itself will make sure that your Python scripts keep running.

If you really want to use a batchfile for that, you might need one of the following commandline commands:

```
tasklist          // for finding is Python is running
wmic process list // for finding which Python script is running
```